# OpenVPN - errno=36 when connecting

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, openvpn

When attempting to connect to the vpn, it seems to fail almost instantly after connecting. The logs below state that the connection response is getting blocked somehow by the proxy.

```
Oct 21 10:55:17: Viscosity Mac 1.5.2 (1242)
Oct 21 10:55:17: Viscosity OpenVPN Engine Started
Oct 21 10:55:17: Running on Mac OS X 10.10
Oct 21 10:55:17: ---------
Oct 21 10:55:17: Checking reachability status of connection...
Oct 21 10:55:17: Connection is reachable. Starting connection attempt.
Oct 21 10:55:17: OpenVPN 2.3.4 x86_64-apple-darwin [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6]         built on Oct 16 2014
Oct 21 10:55:17: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014, LZO 2.08
Oct 21 10:55:20: Control Channel Authentication: using     '/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/connection.zAdVg4/ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key     file
Oct 21 10:55:20: Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]153.107.39.10:8080     [nonblock]
Oct 21 10:55:21: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]153.107.39.10:8080
Oct 21 10:55:22: recv_line: TCP port read failed on recv(): Operation now in progress (errno=36)
Oct 21 10:55:22: SIGTERM[soft,init_instance] received, process exiting
```

A SSH tunnel however, connects fine through the proxy. What is the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the VPN protocol, from PPTP to L2TP or OPENVPN.
Try to connect to some other servers.
Or maybe you have already login on other devices.